# Google Speech Recognition API Result returns only metadata

Tags: google-apps-script, google-speech-api

I'm using this [google app script](https://ctrlq.org/code/20550-cloud-speech-api-with-service-account) for asynchronous speech recognition. It works perfectly fine with files under one minute but the result I get for a longer file (~12 mins) is this:

```js
[18-11-18 08:19:52:104 EST] {
  "name": "5822702390902833748",
  "metadata": {
    "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.speech.v1.LongRunningRecognizeMetadata",
    "startTime": "2018-11-18T13:19:21.769945Z",
    "lastUpdateTime": "2018-11-18T13:19:21.950214Z"
  }
}
```

With no "transcript". 
I've upgraded my google cloud account to payed subscription.
And this is the encoding of the file:

File Size: 15.0M     Bit Rate: 162k
  Encoding: FLAC          Info: Processed by SoX
  Channels: 1 @ 16-bit
Samplerate: 16000Hz
Replaygain: off
  Duration: 00:12:20.65

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It sounds nothing you are missing, you just need to wait until the operation is done.

Basically if you don't use a Speech client library, you should make an operation checker to get operation metadata which will be including the progress of your long running recognize.

More info can be found here: https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/reference/rest/v1/operations